# React Native First Project Built Error: Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to run my first `React Native` project and getting bellow error:

> error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1:
> gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE:
> Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine
> the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not
> determine the  dependencies of null. > java.io.IOException: The
> filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect * Try: >
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info
> or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get
> full insights. > Get more help at  https://help.gradle.org. BUILD
> FAILED in 6s.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. This is what works for me.

This is how it functions for me.

I accessed Android Studio and opened the Android Project. This can be found at YourReactNativeProjectFolder/Android.

You may find this at yourreactnativeprojectfolder/android.

The setting was missing when I opened this project in Android Studio. Give Android Studio some time to configure it and ask you to update the Gradle. After updating Gradle, you may launch your project from Android Studio or by running it from the command line with "npx react-native run-android".

GitHub link : https://github.com/NativeScript/android/issues/553